# Can we always find $X$ such that $X[FF^T]_+=[FF^T]_-$ for arbitrary matrix $F$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that it is not always possible to find $X$ that satisfies $XB=C$ (e.g. take $B=0$ and $C\neq0$)

But what if $B=[FF^T]_+$ and $C=[FF^T]_-$ for arbitrary $F$? where $[A]_+$ ($[A]_-$) is the positive (negative) part of the components of $A$

I am assuming all numbers to be real.

So the question is: for arbitrary real $F$ (square or rectangular) can we always find $X$ such that $X[FF^T]_+=[FF^T]_-$?

If so, how to prove it? If not, can you find a counter-example?

My intuition tells me that this is not always true but all examples I tried turned out to be true.

Comment: Maybe consider a case where all entries of $FF^T$ are negative except the diagonal entries? Then you would expect that there is "not enough information" in $B$, similar to your $B=0,C \neq 0$ example).

Comment: I thought about that, but then $[FF^T]_+$ is a diagonal matrix, which is invertible, so $X$ can be found by the expression $X=[FF^T]_-[FF^T]_+^{-1}$

Comment: What if one of the rows of $F$ is just zero?

Comment: adding rows of $0$s to $F$ just increases the dimension of $FF^T$ (it adds a zero row and zero column, which we can consider to be the last. These new rows/col appear on both sides of the equation). I think by doing that one is adding more freedom to the choice of $X$ than without the zero row

Comment: Ah, yes, now you're just dealing with non-uniqueness not non-existence. Interesting question.